# Get particular key value from json in android (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm beginner in android (Kotlin).I am getting the Following json from the HTTP Response.

```json
{
    "status": 1,
    "userDetails": [
        {
            "AL_ID": "2",
            "User_Id": "admin",
            "User_Password": "admin",
            "Created_Date": "2020-07-30 11:23:55"
        }
    ],
    "lastlogin": "2020-08-20 12:29:47"
}
```

I want to get status value from this json. How to get it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the built-in [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/org/json/JSONObject) and do something as shown below.

```
val json = JSONObject(jsonString) // String instance holding the above json
val status = json.getInt("status")
```

Having said that, I'd recommend you to take a look at [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) (for JSON serialization and deserialization) and [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) (an HTTP client for Android).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Gson library too, for android development in kotlin.

Also I would suggest to have the same DATA classes in kotlin as in database. In that way you can map objects fromJson and toJson with one line of code.

I found article that explains in details how to use Gson library with kotlin.

https://medium.com/@hissain.khan/parsing-with-google-gson-library-in-android-kotlin-7920e26f5520